# Weird behavior TinyMCE text editor on IE

Tags: html, tinymce-4

[image: screenshot]

I use TinyMCE 4.3.3 text editor and it works fine on Firefox and chrome but it has issue with IE. When I click in the editor area it gives some small boxes (as shown in the image highlighted in red) and makes the editor disabled.

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you without seeing running code.  Perhaps you can make a running sample of this on TinyMCE Fiddle or JS Fiddle?  Please review the guidelines for creating a complete, minimal, and verifiable example:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: it is hard to replicate the same issue on the online editors, i tried it though. But explained and discussed the issue with the TinyMCE team, they ended up saying that might be browser related issue. I appreciate your effort to answer my question @MichaelFromin